# c++ chrono timing is wrong?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have a thread that performs some image processing inside a while(true) loop. I want to time the processing time. I do this like so:

```
while(true){
    auto start_prof = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //doing image processing stuff here
    auto stop_prof = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration_prof = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop_prof - start_prof);
}
```

My issue is that duration_prof gives me a value around 20000 ms (= 20 seconds) which is clearly wrong, as the results from the image processing code is ready within a split-second.

So what is going on? The code is running in a thread, does that affect the timing with chrono?

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: How do you observe the duration? If you print it to the console, please show us how.

Comment: Works as expected [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c75cacba5cd807ae).

Comment: I save the duration to a log file. Logger(std::to_string(duration_prof.count()));

Comment: Is `Logger(...)` threadsafe?  Is it possible the log output from multiple threads is getting mixed up/interwoven?